# How can I encrypt the output of mysqldump using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, mysql

I use this code to create dump files of my database.
Now what I want, if possible, is to encrypt it so that when it is viewed in notepad or anything similar, average users cannot read it.

```
Call isDirectoryExist()
    Call createDbBackupName()

    Dim myProcess As Process = New Process

    Dim strUser As String = "superadmin"

    ' MsgBox(" --host=localhost --user='" & strUser & "'   --password """ & strDbName & """  -r """ & strPath & newDBName & """ ")

    Process.Start("C:/MySQL/bin/mysqldump.exe", " --host=localhost --user='" & strUser & "'   --password=1234 """ & strDbName & """  -r """ & strPath & newDBName & """ ")
```

I also have an option to restore these files. using these codes.

```
Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
    strm = ofpSQL.OpenFile
    txtRestore.Text = ofpSQL.FileName.ToString

    If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then


        Dim dbToRestore As String = ofpSQL.FileName.ToString

        Dim myProcess As New Process()
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\MySQL\bin\"
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcess.Start()
        Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
        Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -u superadmin --password=1234 """ & strDbName & """ < """ & ofpSQL.FileName.ToString & """ ")
        myStreamWriter.Close()
        myProcess.WaitForExit()
        myProcess.Close()

        strm.Close()
    End If
```

Of course, if it encrypted, it has to be decrypted before querying the dump file.

I have no idea what encryption I can do in vb.net and mysql

Anyway, if I happen to know one, I dont know how can i use it.
Any help and input will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

I modified my first code

```
Process.Start("C:/MySQL/bin/mysqldump.exe", " --host=localhost --user='" & strUser & "'   --password=1234 """ & strDbName & """  -r """ & strPath & newDBName & """, --cipher /e /a '" & newDBName & "' ")
```

but the output file contains nothing whatsover. TIA

Comment: It looks like that last command you tried to run is from [this question over on DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5831/how-do-you-encrypt-data-while-performing-a-mysqldump).  The command line there invokes an *external program* called cipher to perform the encryption.  It's not a command line argument to mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this,

```
Process.Start("C:/MySQL/bin/mysqldump.exe", " --host=localhost --user='" & strUser & "'   --password=1234 """ & strDbName & """  -r """ & strPath & newDBName & """")
Process.WaitForExit()
Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\cipher.exe", "/e /a '" & strPath & newDBName & "' ")
```